# Put all elements in a dict form that have the same name

Tags: python, regex

I have a list such as:

```
list=["Chrm_23-56_python_regius","Chrm_3-89_elephant_regius",
      "Chrm_13-56_monkey_regius","Chrm_13-34_rat_regius","Chrm_67-123_python_regius",
      "chrm_90-345_elephant_regius","Chrm_67-124_monkey_regius",
      "Chrm_345-456_rat_regius","Chrm_789-1000_python_regius"]
```

and the idea is to put all element in a `dict` form that have the same name (without the `number-number`) part.
and get something like:

```
dict = {'key1': ['Chrm_23-56_python_regius','Chrm_67-123_python_regius','Chrm_789-1000_python_regius'],
        'key2': ['Chrm_3-89_elephant_regius','chrm_90-345_elephant_regius'],
        'key3': ['Chrm_13-56_monkey_regius','Chrm_67-124_monkey_regius'],
        'key4': ['Chrm_13-34_rat_regius','Chrm_345-456_rat_regius']}
```

As you can see for instance, in the `key1`, the 3 values (without the number-number) are = to `Chrm__python_regius`.

I know how to see which element is the same without the `number-number` part by doing:

```
for i in list:
    print(re.sub(r'[\d]+[-]+[\d]+', '',i)
```

But I do not know how to create a `dict` and add in the same keys the values that have the same name structure. Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using regex: --> `re.sub(r"\d*\-\d*", "", i)`

**Ex:**

```
import re
from collections import defaultdict
lst=["Chrm_23-56_python_regius","Chrm_3-89_elephant_regius","Chrm_13-56_monkey_regius","Chrm_13-34_rat_regius","Chrm_67-123_python_regius","chrm_90-345_elephant_regius","Chrm_67-124_monkey_regius","Chrm_345-456_rat_regius","Chrm_789-1000_python_regius"]

result = defaultdict(list)
for i in lst:
    result[re.sub(r"\d*\-\d*", "", i)].append(i)
print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'Chrm__elephant_regius': ['Chrm_3-89_elephant_regius'], 'Chrm__python_regius': ['Chrm_23-56_python_regius', 'Chrm_67-123_python_regius', 'Chrm_789-1000_python_regius'], 'Chrm__monkey_regius': ['Chrm_13-56_monkey_regius', 'Chrm_67-124_monkey_regius'], 'Chrm__rat_regius': ['Chrm_13-34_rat_regius', 'Chrm_345-456_rat_regius'], 'chrm__elephant_regius': ['chrm_90-345_elephant_regius']})
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `itertools.groupby`:

```
import itertools

func = lambda x:x.split('_')[-2]
l = sorted(l, key=func)
d = {'key%s' % i: list(g) for i, (k,g) in enumerate(itertools.groupby(l, func))}
{'key0': ['Chrm_3-89_elephant_regius', 'chrm_90-345_elephant_regius'],
 'key1': ['Chrm_13-56_monkey_regius', 'Chrm_67-124_monkey_regius'],
 'key2': ['Chrm_23-56_python_regius',
  'Chrm_67-123_python_regius',
  'Chrm_789-1000_python_regius'],
 'key3': ['Chrm_13-34_rat_regius', 'Chrm_345-456_rat_regius']}
```

Note:

- `func` part creates a function which extract your desired key from each element of given `iterable`.
- `itertools.groupby` assumes the `iterable` is *sorted*. Thus `sorted` or `list.sort` is necessary before using it.
- `itertools.groupby` then returns grouped object.

Comment: you may want to explain how this works, its pretty complex for a newbie to understand

Comment: from this point do you know how can I sort values in each key in ascending way and get for instance from : `key0': ['Chrm_100-500_elephant_regius', 'chrm_0-80_elephant_regius']` to `key0': ['Chrm_0-80_elephant_regius', 'chrm_100-500_elephant_regius']`  ?

Comment: @Chris what is NewLambdaWithNewKey ?

Comment: @chippycentra Try use `sorted(g)` instead of `list(g)`. Let me know which integer you want to do the sort